# Regex - match pattern inside specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regular expression that matches all the strings that start with `indexOf("`, contain any string ending with `.php` and end with `")`.
Example: `indexOf("products.php")`
I never used the regular expression syntax before, tried to have a look at the docs but I couldn't find the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/indexOf\("[\w\.]+php"\)/g` look here: https://regexr.com/43rc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something like this will do it

```
indexOf\("(\w*\.php)"\)
```

It will capture the filename as a capture group, which I suspect is what you want.

```js
var m = "indexOf(\"foo.php\")".match(/indexOf\("(\w*\.php)"\)/);
console.log(m[0]);
console.log(m[1]);
```

Comment: This won't take into account file names like `my.file.php`

Comment: and I bet: to find for example only `indexOf("products.php")` I need to replace it with `indexOf\("(prodotti*\.php)"\)` , right?

Comment: @UrbiJr uhm... no that wont work. `prodotti` != `product`

Comment: oh yes sorry, I forgot to translate, however that was what i meant :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
indexOf\(("|')(.*?.php)("|')\)
```

- matches first the text indexOf(
- then " or '
- then 0 or more characters except linebreaks with .*
- questionmark makes it non greedy (taking as little as it can) until
  it finds .php quote and )
- then " or '
- ending with a )

  indexOf('myfile.php.php.php').php

Would result in indexOf('myfile.php.php.php')

Comment: I think `indexOf\(("|')(.*?.php)\1\)` is better. Because your code will match `indexOf("somefile.php')` notice that the string started with double quotes and ended with single quote

Comment: Correct, I just assumed no one combines double quote with single quote. Because that would not be smart.